# How echo in bash file using SSH and Sudo

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal, sudo

So here my code:

```bash
$ssh_primary "echo $primary_ssh_password | sudo -S rm /etc/mysql/my.cnf"
$ssh_primary "echo $primary_ssh_password | sudo -S touch /etc/mysql/my.cnf"
$ssh_primary "echo \"[client-server]\nsocket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock\n\n!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/\n!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/\n[mariadb]\nlog-bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log\nserver_id=1\nlog-basename=master1\nbinlog-format=mixed\nlog_error=mariadb_primary.err\nbind-address = 0.0.0.0\n\" > (echo $primary_ssh_password | sudo -S /etc/mysql/my.cnf)"
$ssh_primary "echo $primary_ssh_password | sudo -S systemctl restart mariadb"
```

and more here my problem:

```bash
$ssh_primary "echo \"[client-server]\nsocket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock\n\n!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/\n!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/\n[mariadb]\nlog-bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log\nserver_id=1\nlog-basename=master1\nbinlog-format=mixed\nlog_error=mariadb_primary.err\nbind-address = 0.0.0.0\n\" > (echo $primary_ssh_password | sudo -S /etc/mysql/my.cnf)"
```

Expect output: I would have full access on this file, without having a prompt for password, but I dont really know how.. Can someone help me please?

I tried to do the opposite of what I had, but it doesn't work at all.
I've done changes in /etc/sudoers.

Comment: Do you use ssh keys?

Comment: Actually no I don't use it

Comment: Use keys and ssh agent to make passwordless connection

Comment: About `sudo` you can set it to be also passwordless

Comment: So your problem is how to provide the password automatically, without being prompted, right? Are you talking about the password for ssh or for sudo? BTW, you have not shown the content of `ssh_primary`.

Comment: Yeah that's right, "sshpass -p $primary_ssh_password ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p $primary_ssh_port $primary_ssh_user@$primary_ssh_host" here the content

Comment: You did not specify, which OS you are using. Linux sudo and BSD sudo differ.

Comment: So, if I understand your question correctly, ssh and the sudo on the target machine have the identical password?

Comment: Yes, exactly its for testing before launch in prod, and I use Debian for information